# Reversing araylist of integers manually

Tags: java

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> reverse (ArrayList<Integer> n) {
    ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(int i = 0; i < n.size(); i++) {
        int j = n.size() - i - 1; 
        result.add(i, n.get(j));
    }

    return result;
}
```

but if i enter an array `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10` 
the result    is `10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,10`

Where is my mistake?

Comment: This is probably the least efficient way to reverse an arraylist i've ever seen.

Comment: @Wug What's so inefficient about it then?

Comment: @Thousand: inserting into an array list at an arbitrary index is O(n), so the algorithm is O(n^2)

Comment: @Thousand Re: Wug's Comment:  Using the `add(element)` (one argument instead of 2) is O(1) amortized, but adds the element at the end.  Restructuring the `for` loop would allow this, and make the program many times faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, what you have there works fine. But you can simplify your `for`-loop by iterating 'backwards':

```
for(int i = n.size() - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--)
    result.add(n.get(i));
```

---

Oh, and one more thing I should mention. When you declare the list `result`, you might want to specify its capacity, since you know what it will be. i.e.:

```
ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>(n.size());
```

Comment: i enter 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 and the output is 10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,10

Comment: @user1795732 Are you accidentally printing a `0` at the end there? I ran your code with this example to double-check and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 3):

Uses `n.size() / 2` swaps (the fewest possible) and runs in linear time.

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> reverse (ArrayList<Integer> n)
{
    for (int i = 0, j = n.size() - 1, t; i <= size / 2; ++i, --j)
    {
        t = n.get(i);
        n.set(i, n.get(j));
        n.set(j, t);
    }
    return n;
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach, but are you sure it's any faster than just looping all the way through the list? (Since you do 2 `set`-operations per iteration)

Comment: It's definitely more efficient with native arrays.  You lose out a bit with the wrapped access of arraylists.

Comment: Yea that would make sense I suppose. Anyway, +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

> Collections.reverse(arrayList);

In case you still want to go for a manual one,

```
     public ArrayList<Integer> reverse(ArrayList<Integer> arrayList) {
        ArrayList<Integer> result = (ArrayList<Integer>)list.clone();
        for (int start=0,end=result.size()-1;start<end;start++,end--) {
           swap(result,start,end) ;
        }
        return result;
     }
     public void swap(ArrayList<Integer> temp, int front, int back) {
        Integer i = temp.set(front,temp.get(back)) ;
        temp.set(back, i) ;
     }
```

Comment: sorry but did he mention that he wants to do it manually? and is my solution going to throw errors?

Comment: I'm not going to downvote you because your solution is better than homerolling it in every respect.  You don't gain anything from knowing how to reverse an array.  Anyone knows how to do it, if you don't you're dumb as rocks.  Once you get that far, its a waste of time to write code that does it because its a wheel that already comes in many shapes and sizes.  The only thing wrong with this answer is that it isn't what the asker wanted.

Comment: @Thousand check out my answer...added a manual way of doing it.

Comment: @Arham Your solution modifies the original list - the OP's method is supposed to return a new `ArrayList`.

Comment: @A.R.S.: OP's does do it that way, yes. But modifying the arraylist is probably just as good. If that's not good enough you can use `otherN = reverse(n.clone());`

Comment: @A.R.S. but don't you think a simple tweak would solve that problem and OP ca do that? My aim was to show a way of reversing be it in the same array or in a secondary resultant array.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work for lists with even numbers of items